# this.setState React bind issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to pass the `changePage` class method into a child component called `SideBar`. When the `changePage` method is then triggered by an `onClick` event in the child component I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.SetState is not a function

From what I could find in other similar posts I need to bind the `changePage` method to this. I have done that but I still can't manage to get is to work.

I also saw many suggestions to use ES6 arrow functions for my methods but I get the exact same error message if I do.

I'm still quite new at web development and any help would be appreciated.

Parent Component called Main:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Content from './Content';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

export default class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  this.state = {
   selectedPage: 'home',
   pages: ['home','about','skills','contact'],
  };
  this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
 }

 changePage(page) {
  console.log(page);
  this.SetState({
   selectedPage: page,
   pages: ['home','about','skills','contact']
  });
 };

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <div id="sidebar" className="side-bar">
     <Sidebar
      changePage={this.changePage}
      selectedPage={this.state.selectedPage}
      pages={this.state.pages}
     />
    </div>

    <div id="main" className="main-content">
     <Content
      selectedPage={this.state.selectedPage}
     />
    </div>
   </div>
  )
 } 
}
```

Child Component:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {
 render() {
  console.log("content props",this.props);

  const buttons = this.props.pages.map(button => 
   <span
    className='nav-button'
    id={button}
    key={button}
    onClick={() => this.props.changePage(button)}
   >
       <img src={`./app/images/${button}.svg`} />
      </span>
  );
   
  return (
   <div>
    <span>
        <img className='headshot' src='./app/images/headshot.jpg' />
       </span>

       <div className='nav-container'>
        {buttons}
       </div>
      </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Typo?: `SetState` should be `setState` (lowercase first letter)?

Comment: SetState? Remember that js is a case sensitive language. The correct name of the method is `setState`

Comment: Yes that's it! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error: `this.SetState`. Change it to `this.setState`.

Comment: Yes that's it! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The typo in setState was causing the error, but you may want consider a cleaner way to bind the parent `this` on the `changePage` prop. Your way works, but if you changed sidebar Component inclusion to:

```
<Sidebar
    changePage={ (page) => this.changePage(page)}
    selectedPage={this.state.selectedPage}
    pages={this.state.pages}
/>
```

That may make it clearer what is going on (changePage prop is a function which takes one parameter and passes that parameter to instance method this.changePage), and removes the binding gymnastics in the constructor.

Comment: The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the Sidebar renders.  React team generally recommends binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.